# Tensor Flow installation on RHEL 7

Tags: installation, tensorflow, six

I am new to Tensor Flow and trying to install it on my RHEL 7 machine using the below command. I cannot connect the machine directly to internet due to some restrictions so using a whl file downloaded from Tensor flow site.

```
pip install tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

But getting error as below :

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement six>=1.10.0
>   (from tensorflow==0.5.0) (from versions: ) No matching distribution
>   found for six>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow==0.5.0)

I am using pip installed on my machine through anaconda and have python 2.7 installed on the machine as well

Can you please help me to decode the error?

Comment: Thanks Salvador couldn't get the meaning at first, now its done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  Your six package needs to be updated.  Try:

```
easy_install --upgrade six
```

Note: I am doing this from within a virtual environment and I do have internet.

Comment: I was having similar issue and none of `easy_install` and `pip` statements helped. They were errorring  'No module named six'. I deleted my packages folder (`rm -rf ~/Library/Python/`), and then I was able to run `pip install six`