# How do I fix an exception caused by trying to install Tensorflow?

Tags: python, pip, tensorflow

So I'm doing a pip installation of Tensorflow, and every time I run sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.8.0-py2-none-any.whl, I get this obnoxious error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 726, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 746, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', 
'/tmp/pip-OGQupl-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', 
"[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-OGQupl-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', 
'/tmp/pip-OGQupl-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', 
"[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-OGQupl-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), 
('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', 
'/tmp/pip-OGQupl-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', 
"[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-OGQupl-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), 
('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', 
'/tmp/pip-OGQupl-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', 
"[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-OGQupl-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), 
('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', 
'/tmp/pip-OGQupl-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', 
"[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-OGQupl-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
```

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
sudo -H pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.8.0-py2-none-any.whl --upgrade --ignore-installed six
```

Answer (score 1):

I've heard this error occurs with 32bit systems as tensorflow is supposed to run on 64bit.

See this link https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33

Just got my installation of tensorflow working. I switched from using ubuntu 16 to 14. So using Ubuntu14.04.5 x64 works.

Checkout this answer for ideal system requirements for tensorflow:

[Tensorflow recommended system specifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529927/tensorflow-recommended-system-specifications)